# JAVA - как собирается .jar?

Tags: java, jar

Подскажите "обывателю" пожалуйста какой мой ход действий.

1. Есть jar-файл
2. Если его открыть как архив, то в нем будут .class и .java файлы
3. .class скомпилированные
4. .java видимо исходники, так как они читаются

Хочу поменять в исходнике часть функции. В этом понимание есть.
Как мне потом собрать обратно этот jar правильно? 
Нужно скомпилировать из .java обратно в .class и потом упаковать в jar.
Я могу просто скомпилированный .class добавить внутрь jar как в архив? Или нужно еще как-то пересобирать весь jar?
Внутри jar есть еще манифест, но в нем ничего не прописано, только Manifest-Version: 1.0

Comment: Да, можно поменять .java файл, скомпилировать его и подложить в архив вместо предыдущего. А можно прям поменять содержимое .class файла и ничего не придется перекомпиливать)

Answer (score 6):

По сути. jar - это обычный ZIP-файл. Иногда бывает с подписями, контрольными суммами тогда что-то в нём исправить не получится. Если у вас простой файл, вы можете исправить java файл, перекомпилировать его с помощью javac в class файл и собрать jar файл заново с помощью обычного архиватора. В составе JDK есть файл JAR.EXE (если у вас Windows), который легко сделает это. Конечно удобнее всё делать в какой-либо Java IDE, если она у вас есть.

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо да все проще получается

Answer (score 2):

Если используешь maven добавь в пом файле должно быть jar или соответствующий плагин. Читай мануал.

```
javac MyApp.java
jar -cf myJar.jar myApp
```